# How to ask a question with double accusative?

Tags: word-order, accusative, question

Edit: *thanks to the comments/answers, I understand now that my initial question is wrong. There is one nominative and one accusative in this question.*

Today I wanted to transform the affirmative sentence

> Das Licht stört Sie

in a question. But then I could not really choose between:

> Stört das Licht Sie?

and

> Stört Sie das Licht?

The first one seems to follow the logical German rules (Verb, Subject, Object). But the second one sounds more correct although it breaks the rules I know of how Germans ask questions. The first one sounds really weird to me.

Which one is correct?

Comment: _"Stört Sie das Licht?"_ is correct.

Comment: Where is the double accusative? Both versions are correct although the second one is more common

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off there are not two accusatives there, das Licht is nominative.

The second one is better as others have said, the reason this is correct is that generally in  German questions the word order after the initial verb is all pronouns THEN the noun subject. Sie is a pronoun and as such it goes before the noun subject.
So:

> Stört Sie das Licht?

is correct.

Comment: Sie could mean *you*. In this case, uppercase is correct.

Comment: Oh ignore me I'll edit it, just realised I am an idiot